# How to change console code to 1252?

Tags: windows, postgresql, git-bash

I am trying to use PostgreSQL on Windows 8 using the command line provided by Git Bash so I can run Unix like commands. When accessing Postgres with the following command: `psql -U postgres` I get:

> Warning: Console code page (850) differs from Windows code page (1252)
>   etc...

in the Windows command tool, I just need to type `chcp 1252` before accessing Postgres so the warning doesn't show up. What's the equivalent command in unix/git bash?

I tried to do `chcp 1252` or `chcp` from Git bash but it outputs:

> sh.exe": chcp: command not found

Any ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try "chcp.com 1252".

Git bash doesn't suppose ".com" as a implicit executable postfix.
It can't expand "chcp" to correct executable, so you should type fully "chcp.com".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This is an answer for "I want to issue chcp command on Git Bash".  What's wrong?

Comment: You should explain your answer a little bit more... Maybe try explaining why bash can't expand `chcp`

Answer (score 3):

You're using the Windows `psql.exe` binary under the msys `bash`.

This may not work well, as `psql.exe` is a Win32 binary. It uses stdio, but not the same way bash expects.

You'll want to either use a `psql` built against msys (not trivial), or use `psql` under `cmd.exe` or powershell.

Comment: Thank you for this 3 year old comment. I had a suspicion that this was a part of all my problems, and spelling it out like this has steered me in a better direction.